# How can these queries join each other

Tags: sqlite

I want these two queries to create one table. I am not able to add `date_recieved` to the first queries. I want them to be in the same table. 
Would appreciate help.

```
select CustomerFIRSTNAME, CustomerLASTNAME, VintageWatch.WATCHID, NumberUsed, PRICE, BRANDNAME, (PRICE*(NumberUsed )) as CostPrice
from partsused
inner join customers on partsused.NumberUsed = CUSTID 
inner join VintageWatch on VintageWatch.WATCHID = SERVICETICKETID;


.print ""
.print "MONTH REPORT"
.print ""
select DATE_RECIEVED as FEBRUARY
from serviceticket
where DATE_RECIEVED like '14/02/19'
or DATE_RECIEVED > '14/02/19';
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_before_E_except_after_C

Comment: A date string like `dd/mm/yy` is not something you can meaningfully compare.... `29/05/19` compares greater than `10/06/19` for example even though it represents an earlier date. You're better off using one of the formats understood by sqlite [date and time functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html), which can be ordered.